# TwoWay Manual Binding Implementation for ListBox.SelectedItems?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

I've been trying to see if there is an easy/clever way to implement binding to ListBox.SelectedItems. If you have tried yourself, you will know, that markup binding using BindingExtension will not work - the property doesn't support it. So you are left with wiring up a handler for SelectionChanged and trying that route. The closest I've gotten is this post:

<strike>http://alexshed.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!71C72270309CE838!149.entry</strike>

*Update: the above mentioned blog is no longer available, that author's current blog [is here](http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/SoaringCode/Default.aspx) and the closest I could find to the referenced blog post is [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1584718/109702).*

Which implements all the necessary C# in a handy attached property. But it implements the "binding" as a One-Way, Target to Source. I'd like Two-Way binding.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 41):

I've found an elegant solution, and I've just found time to write a [blog post about it](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html).

What I did was to create an attached property, SynchronizedSelectedItems that you can set on the ListBox (or DataGrid in fact). You databind this to a collection, and then, with a bit of magic, the SelectedItems property on the ListBox and your collection are kept in sync. You can download all the code from my blog post.

The "magic" is a class which listens out for CollectionChanged events in either collection, and propagates the changes to the other.

Comment: I try to adopt your souce code to Silverlight but it doesn't work. Do you have any example in Silverlight?

Comment: Not able to download the sample. Could you share the Extended behaviour code in blog post or share the code some where else please.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution for this, and the proposed seemed overly complex.  So, here is a new two way binding solution that is limited to just an attached property, and uses weak event handling for watching changes in the defined dependency property.  I didn't spend any time making this bulletproof, but it does work.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class ListBoxHelper
    {
        private static Dictionary<int, bool> SynchToDPInProcessDictionary = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
        private static Dictionary<int, bool> SynchToLBInProcessDictionary = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedItems", typeof(IList), typeof(ListBoxHelper),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((IList)null,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedItemsChanged)));

        public static IList GetSelectedItems(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (IList)d.GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSelectedItems(DependencyObject d, IList value)
        {
            d.SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var listBox = d as ListBox;
            if (listBox == null) 
                throw new InvalidOperationException("ListBoxHelper should only be used with ListBox or ListBox derived classes (like ListView).");

            int hashcode = listBox.GetHashCode();

            // Gets set on the initial binding.
            if (!SynchToDPInProcessDictionary.ContainsKey(hashcode))
            {
                SynchToDPInProcessDictionary[hashcode] = false;
                SynchToLBInProcessDictionary[hashcode] = false;

                var observableCollection = GetSelectedItems(listBox) as INotifyCollectionChanged;
                if (observableCollection != null)
                {
                    // Create a weak CollectionChanged event handler on the SelectedItems property
                    // that synchronizes the collection back to the listbox.
                    CollectionChangedEventManager.AddHandler(observableCollection,
                        delegate(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e2)
                        {
                            SyncToLBSelectedItems(GetSelectedItems(d), (ListBox)d);
                        });
                }
            }

            SynchToDPSelectedItems(listBox);
            listBox.SelectionChanged += delegate
            {
                SynchToDPSelectedItems(listBox);
            };
        }


        private static void SynchToDPSelectedItems(ListBox listBox)
        {
            int hashcode = listBox.GetHashCode();
            if (SynchToLBInProcessDictionary[hashcode]) return;

            SynchToDPInProcessDictionary[hashcode] = true;
            try
            {
                IList dpSelectedItems = GetSelectedItems(listBox);
                dpSelectedItems.Clear();
                if (listBox.SelectedItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in listBox.SelectedItems)
                        dpSelectedItems.Add(item);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                SynchToDPInProcessDictionary[hashcode] = false;
            }
        }

        private static void SyncToLBSelectedItems(IList dpSelectedItems, ListBox listBox)
        {
            int hashcode = listBox.GetHashCode();
            if (SynchToDPInProcessDictionary[hashcode]) return;

            SynchToLBInProcessDictionary[hashcode] = true;
            try
            {
                listBox.SelectedItems.Clear();
                if (dpSelectedItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in dpSelectedItems)
                        listBox.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                SynchToLBInProcessDictionary[hashcode] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```