# WPF ListBox + Binding + IDataErrorInfo =?

Tags: .net, wpf, validation, data-binding, listbox

I have a WPF MVVM application. In the View I have a multiselect `ListBox`. In the ViewModel I have a property for the selected items in the List.

Using a technique similar to the one in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414074/twoway-manual-binding-implementation-for-listbox-selecteditems) question I can bind my property to the `ListBox`.

But I also want to do data validation via `IDataErrorInfo`. All I want to do is check that the user has selected at least one item in the list. Adding `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` to the binding doesn't work.

Is there any way to have a multiselect listbox that's databound with IDataErrorInfo?

Comment: Can you post your code?  Define "doesn't work"?  Are you getting an error?  Is the imlementation of IDataErrorInfo called?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a behavior for binding ViewModel's List with ListBox's selected items, manually update the binding after add/remove item(s):

```
var binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, SelectedItemsListBoxBehavior.SelectedItemsProperty);
if (binding != null)binding.UpdateSource();
```

Comment: binding.ValidateWhithoutUpdate() is available but doesn't seem to do the job.

Answer (score -1):

Even it is multiselect ListBox you can bind SelectedItem

```
 SelectedItem="{Binding FakeSelectedItem, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
```

and then do a validation when this property changes.

PS
For the binding I am using this solution [MVVM Multiselect Listbox](http://www.gbogea.com/2010/01/02/mvvm-multiselect-listbox)