# Why is my namespace not recognized in Visual Studio / xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, namespaces

these are my 2 classes a Attachable Property SelectedItems:

code is from here: [Sync SelectedItems in a muliselect listbox with a collection in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297643/sync-selecteditems-in-a-muliselect-listbox-with-a-collection-in-viewmodel)

The namespace TBM.Helper is for sure proper as it works for other classes too.

The namespace reference is also in the xaml file AND the SelectedItems.cs file!

```
xmlns:Helper="clr_namespace:TBM.Helper"
```

But `<ListBox Helper:SelectedItems.Items="{Binding SelectedItems}" ...`

does not work because =>

**The property 'SelectedItems.Items' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr_namespace:TBM.Helper'. 
The attachable property 'Items' was not found in type 'SelectedItems**

What do I have to change ?

```
    using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows;

namespace TBM.Helper
{
    public static class SelectedItems : DependencyObject
    {
        private static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsBehaviorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "SelectedItemsBehavior",
                typeof(SelectedItemsBehavior),
                typeof(ListBox),
                null);

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Items",
            typeof(IList),
            typeof(SelectedItems),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, ItemsPropertyChanged));

    public static void SetItems(ListBox listBox, IList list) { listBox.SetValue(ItemsProperty, list); }
    public static IList GetItems(ListBox listBox) { return listBox.GetValue(ItemsProperty) as IList; }

    private static void ItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = d as ListBox;
        if (target != null)
        {
            GetOrCreateBehavior(target, e.NewValue as IList);
        }
    }

    private static SelectedItemsBehavior GetOrCreateBehavior(ListBox target, IList list)
    {
        var behavior = target.GetValue(SelectedItemsBehaviorProperty) as SelectedItemsBehavior;
        if (behavior == null)
        {
            behavior = new SelectedItemsBehavior(target, list);
            target.SetValue(SelectedItemsBehaviorProperty, behavior);
        }

        return behavior;
    }
}
```

}

```
using System.Windows;
```

using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections;

namespace TBM.Helper
{
    public class SelectedItemsBehavior
    {
        private readonly ListBox _listBox;
        private readonly IList _boundList;

```
    public SelectedItemsBehavior(ListBox listBox, IList boundList)
    {
        _boundList = boundList;
        _listBox = listBox;

        SetSelectedItems();

        _listBox.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
        _listBox.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
    }

    private void SetSelectedItems()
    {
        _listBox.SelectedItems.Clear();

        foreach (object item in _boundList)
        {
            // References in _boundList might not be the same as in _listBox.Items
            int i = _listBox.Items.IndexOf(item);
            if (i >= 0)
                _listBox.SelectedItems.Add(_listBox.Items[i]);
        }
    }

    private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetSelectedItems();
    }

    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _boundList.Clear();

        foreach (var item in _listBox.SelectedItems)          
            _boundList.Add(item);           
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Sounds like human error and the possibility of providing a clear response is pretty small now.

Comment: Where is the human error? I can still change the namespace if Visual Studio would allow it...

Comment: i am sure there is a question in there somewhere...

Comment: Can you clarify and clean up this repro, accept the answer, or delete the question? I'm confused even after spending a few minutes trying to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

At first I thought it is a typo (and maybe it is), but since your exception also says `clr_namespace:TBM.Helper` with an underscore, I think it might actually be in your code. Try to replace the underscore with a hyphen like this:

```
xmlns:Helper="clr-namespace:TBM.Helper"
```

I did not look through all the other code, so maybe there is another problem. However, you should try the above first. Good luck!

**EDIT:** Is your `SelectedItemsBehavior` class in the same assembly as your XAML? Otherwise, you will have to reference the other assembly in your project and change your namespace declaration to something like this:

```
xmlns:Helper="clr-namespace:TBM.Helper;assembly=MyOtherAssemblyName"
```

Furthermore, you cannot set a base class for a static class:

```
public static class SelectedItems : DependencyObject
```

This is not possible. Simply remove the `: DependencyObject`

If this still does not help, I am out of here. Your code is really messy, at least how you posted it...

Comment: yes very shortly after I opened that thread here I saw that underscore, but that was not the origion problem.