# Silverlight listbox validation: required selection

Tags: silverlight, validation, silverlight-4.0

I want to validate a ListBox: the user must select at least 2 items. The SelectedItems property doesn't support binding. So what now?

I miss the good old days when WinForms and ASP.NET controls had validation events, buttons had the CausesValidation property, etc...

Comment: I would validate through non standard ways like a messagebox after a button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably handle the selected items changed event using a Trigger or Behaviour and then use the INotifyDataErrorInfo to create a validation errors for that control.

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Behaviors-and-Triggers-in-Silverlight-3.aspx

http://attachedwpf.com/blog/2010/03/24/silverlight-4-inotifydataerrorinfo/

Comment: I thought about that, but how will the control be notified of the error? Since I can't bind to it, it won't ask me if there are any errors.

Comment: This seems to show a good way to bind selected items. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297643/sync-selecteditems-in-a-muliselect-listbox-with-a-collection-in-viewmodel/1299544#1299544