# Binding in multiple views to ObservableCollection of selected items (MVVM, SL5)

Tags: data-binding, observablecollection, silverlight-5.0, attachedbehaviors, multiple-views

I'm using MVVM with Silverlight 5. What I want to achieve is to select items in a `ListBox` in one view (e.g. ListView.xaml) and display the selected items in a `ListBox` in another view (e.g. SelectionView.xaml).

My selected items are in an `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` (called `SelectedItems`) that is created via attached behaviour as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297643/sync-selecteditems-in-a-muliselect-listbox-with-a-collection-in-viewmodel)

The problem seems to be that I am using two different XAML files. If I bind a `ListBox` to `SelectedItems` in the same XAML file where the selection happens, the items show up in another `ListBox` in the same view without problems. But in a different file, the `ListBox` stays empty.

Both views use the same `ViewModel` as DataContext.

I would be very happy about some pointers in the right direction. I'm new to SL so perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

This is the code that works:

ListView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Silverlight5App.View.Content.ListView"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Silverlight5App.ViewModel"
    xmlns:behaviours="clr-namespace:Silverlight5App.Behaviours">


    <UserControl.Resources>
        <viewModel:XYPlotViewModel x:Key="ViewModelTest" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelTest}}">
        <StackPanel>            
            <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=XYPoints}"  behaviours:SelectedItems.Items="{Binding SelectedItems}" Name="XYPointsListbox" SelectionMode="Extended" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" Text="{Binding id}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Text="{Binding x}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="2" Text="{Binding y}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}"  Name="XYPointsListboxSelection">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" Text="{Binding id}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Text="{Binding x}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="2" Text="{Binding y}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and this code just gives an empty listbox:

SelectionView.xaml

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Silverlight5App.View.Content.SelectionView"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Silverlight5App.ViewModel"     
    xmlns:behaviours="clr-namespace:Silverlight5App.Behaviours">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <viewModel:XYPlotViewModel x:Key="ViewModelTest" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelTest}}" >       
        <StackPanel>               
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItems}"  Name="XYPointsListboxSelection2">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" Text="{Binding id}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Text="{Binding x}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="2" Text="{Binding y}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

PS: syntax highlighting is set to language-all: lang-xml but doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the **same ViewModel Instance** in order this to work.

You can do it by creating your view model as a Singleton and assign it not via the XAML, but by the code (in either the constructor, or in the PageLoaded Event).

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the info that I needed! I wasn't aware that I created a new instance of my ViewModel. And there is a lot of information out there on how to make a Singleton ViewModel, like [this example](http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/11-08-17/Singleton_ViewModels_in_Silverlight.aspx)