# Binding SelectedItems of Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, collectionview

how can i bind `SelectedItems` of a `ListView`?
My `ListView` has `multipleSelection` attribute and I'm using `CollectionView` for its contents..

I've heard about Attached property and I tried implementing this with the one I found here:
[Sync SelectedItems in a muliselect listbox with a collection in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297643/sync-selecteditems-in-a-muliselect-listbox-with-a-collection-in-viewmodel)

I can multiple select the items by clicking rows but I can't use the `Shift` keyboard for multi-selecting many rows instantly... Also, when I filter my collection and refresh it, my selection are all deselected after the refresh..

How can I make it so that whenever my `CollectionView` refreshes, the previously selecteditems are still selected after the refresh...?

Can someone also help me how to manipulate logically the selected items through my viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should add the `IsSelected` property to the ListViewItem's view model.

Comment: +1 This is what I usually do - add an `IsSelected` property to the object and bind it in the `ListViewItem` Style

Comment: How can this be the "True WPF way"?  It is putting a property that is purely for the view into the model?  I guess if you are willing to convert from your object to a custom ViewModel only object, then you can keep it in the view model.  But still, something that should be View only is getting out.

Comment: @Vaccano: I guess you are confusing Model and ViewModel. I suggested to put a property from a View to the ViewModel. Then you can add calculated property to ViewModel: SelectedItems.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use your own code to keep the selected items after a refresh. Maybe make a copy of your collection before the refresh and afterwards a simple for to check all the checked items in your current collection.

Change your [selectection mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to extended for your listbox for the shift key to work.

As for manipulating logically the selected items, you will have to give a lot more info on what exactly you want done.