# How to get SelectedItems from ListView in my ViewModel

Tags: wpf, listviewitem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Binding SelectedItems of Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999509/binding-selecteditems-of-listview)

I have a ListView and User can select multiple items. I need to get list of items selected from ListView in my View Model.

please suggest to get SelectedItems from ListView.

Thank you

Comment: There is a blog post addressing this problem: http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways I usually do this

If I only need to know what is selected for the purpose of a command, I will setup my `RelayCommand` or `DelegateCommand` in the `ViewModel` to expect a parameter of type `IList<SomeClass>` and pass the `ListView.SelectedItems` in as the `CommandParameter`

```
<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyListView, Path=SelectedItems}" />
```

The other method I often use is to create an `IsSelected` property on whatever data item is being used in the `ListView`, and bind it to the `ListViewItem.IsSelected` property

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
</Style>
```

Then my `ViewModel` can find out if an item is selected or not by looking at it's `IsSelected` property

```
foreach(var item in MyCollection)
{
    if (item.IsSelected)
        // Do work
}
```